# Passing parameters via GET to any url in universal way

Tags: php, get

I have `back_url` given to me from the outside. I need to generate a hash and to make redirect to this `back_url` with this param: `header("Location: $back_url?hash=123sdf")`. But the problem is that I don't know the format of `back_url`.

- It may be `www.example.com` and I do `header("Location: $back_url/?hash=123sdf")` sj that's fine.
- It maybe `www.example.com/?param=value` and if I do h`eader("Location: $back_url/?hash=123sdf")` it's wrong, because it would be `www.example.com/?param=value/?hash=123asd`.

And so on. The question is: what's the universal way to pass params to `back_url` ignoring its format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote this function:

```
 private function addUrlParam(array $params, $url){
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    if(!isset($parsed['query']))
    {
        $slash = '';
        if(substr($url, -1) !== '/')
            $slash = '/';
        $start_with = $slash.'?';
    }
    else
        $start_with = '&';

    $scheme = '';
    if(!isset($parsed['scheme']))
        $scheme = 'http://';

    $query = http_build_query($params);
    return $scheme.$url.$start_with.$query;
}
```

Looks like it's perfect for me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

A complex but very clean way is

- Use [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the query string  (if any) from the URL into an array
- Add `hash` to the resulting array: `$params["hash"] = "1234";`
- Use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to glue the parameters back into a query string
- Take all the components returned by `parse_url()` and glue them back into a full URL

one thing to note is that this dissects the URL into it components and glues it back together, so it's likely it won't work with URLs that are broken in the first place.

Comment: This is the preferred way if the PECL HTTP extension is installed, otherwise http_build_query isn't available.

Comment: I thought it had the same dependancy as http_build_url. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the PECL HTTP extension, use [http_build_url](http://php.net/http_build_url):

```
$url = '...';
$hash = '...';
$new_url = http_build_url($url, array('hash' => $hash), HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY);
```

If you don't have http_build_url, you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) to find the different parts if a URL. Then it's just a matter of pasting them together. [Here's](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#100114) a solution in the manual which can be tailored for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would need to detect if `$back_url` has other query parameters (or GET variables) and append your hash using `?hash=123asd` if it hadn't, or using `&hash=123asd` if indeed it had query parameters.

If you know that `$back_url` is a full url like http://whatever.com/blah/blah (the important part being `http://whatever.com`, you can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse-url) to get all components, and then continue with Pekka's answer. If your `$back_url` doesn't begin with `http://...`, then prepend the right value (I assume `http://$_SERVER['host']` and, again, continue with Pekka's answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've used your comments and wrote small function that's perfect for me